# Вызов диалога из фрагмента

Tags: android, kotlin, dialogfragment

Создал нотификацию, в которой у меня есть некий задаваемый параметр:

```
.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
```

где pendingIntent у меня это переход в MainActivity:

```
val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)
```

Сейчас же хочу чтобы он открывал мне диалог, который находится во фрагменте, диалог во фрагменте открываю следующим образом:

```
activity?.showDialogFragment(ConfirmDetailsDialog.newInstance(model))
```

Как можно безболезненно вызвать данный диалог?

Comment: Как `Activity` должна узнать, что нужно отобразить диалог? Можно добавить в интент `boolean` параметр, например `show_dialog_fragment`. Если параметр `true`, значить выполнить `showDialogFragment(...)`